# Devise and pundit - how to restrict access to devise original views/actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4.2, rolify, pundit

I am using Rails(4.2.1), Devise(3.4.1) and Pundit(1.0.0) and want to restrict the access to devise views(such as /users/edit) by my users role(rolify, 4.0.0).

How my policy should be named or how do I specify which model is referring to ? to match devise's

I tried to copy the devise controllers with a [script](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/Tool:-Generate-and-customize-controllers) in the docs but can't make it work.

What should I do to make this work, couldn't find anything that explain how to do this in a simple way. Just to be sure I am trying to use devise default views

Answer (score -1):

I can recommend this screencast for you: [Authorization with Pundit](https://gorails.com/episodes/authorization-with-pundit)

You can name your policies like your model. For example for the Post model it's PostPolicy.

It's always informative to look at the readme: [Pundit Readme](https://github.com/elabs/pundit)

Comment: Unfortunately this screencast it is not free, and my problem is not with Pundit only, it is about its integration with Devise. I read the docs and understood the Post example, but couldn't get to work with Devise user.

Comment: If you need more help you can post your code to your question.

Comment: Sorry, I can't. Either way, I am hoping for someone that did something like this before to answer or give some direction.